# Mock SERVERPROPERTY in tSQLt

Tags: sql-server, tsqlt

I am writing some logic that has branches based on the SQL Server version. Is there a way to mock `SERVERPROPERTY` in tSQLt?

Edit: Updated question and description with correct function name.

Comment: you wanted this `SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')` ?

Comment: @MitchWheat that is correct.

Comment: @Squirrel Yes, looking further, I will be using SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion'). The intent was to ask if I can mock SQL Server's inbuilt function to hit all branches in my code.

Comment: You're presumably acting differently for different versions for a reason. If that is so, but in fact you're not running on the version you claim to be, doesn't that invalidate any certainty the tests would give you that the code is correct *for the actual version of SQL Server*?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that is why I need to mock the function. I can simulate the environments using the mock function to once return the lower version, and then the desirable version to run both paths.

Comment: Say you have code paths for 2017 and 2019. You do some work and accidentally make the 2017 code path rely on 2019 functionality. Your tests won't pick this up, even with the faked version check, because they *really were running on a 2019 instance*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating your own user defined function as a wrapper, which you can then mock as normal, e.g:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfGetProductMajorVersion()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(128)
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS NVARCHAR(128))
END
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, @Brenton. However, I am aware that we can mock UDFs, I wanted to know if we can do the same for in-built functions like SERVERPROPERTY as well.

Comment: Fair enough. I believe the direct answer is no, you can't mock SERVERPROPERTY. tSQLt doesn't have functions for that and it probably can't because it's a server level function and tSQLt is operating at database level, therefore can only mock database objects. The closest alternative is to use a wrapper like I've described here.